# Calculator is adding numbers instead of subtracting

Tags: java

I just started learning GUI in Java and I was wondering if someone can assist with the problem I'm having. I'm trying to make a calculator, but the problem is whenever I subtract two numbers and click on the equal sign button, it seems to add the 2 numbers instead of subtracting.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Font;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.GridLayout;
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;

  class Colorwindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


      private JButton clear, addition, subtract, divide, multiply, zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, equal;
      private JTextField name, name2, name3;
      private String inputing, solution, solution2, solution3, solution4;
      private boolean AddStatement, SubtractStatement, MultiplyStatement, DivideStatement, statement;
      private JButton SButtonList[] = new JButton[6];
      private JButton NButtonList[] = new JButton[10];
      private String SymbolList[] = {
          "+",
          "-",
          "/",
          "*",
          "=",
          "C"
      };
      private String NumberList[] = {
          "0",
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4",
          "5",
          "6",
          "7",
          "8",
          "9"
      };
      private String NumberList2[] = {
          "0",
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4",
          "5",
          "6",
          "7",
          "8",
          "9"
      };
      private double result[] = new double[10];
      private double number[] = new double[10];
      //AddStatement = false;

      Colorwindow() {

          super();
          setSize(500, 500); //sets size of window
          getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY); //sets backgroundcolor to yellow
          rows 3 column
          JPanel textfont = new JPanel();
          name = new JTextField(30);
          textfont.add(name); //adds textfield
          name.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
          Font bigFont = name.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 70 f);
          name.setFont(bigFont);
          name2 = new JTextField(30);
          //textfont.add(name2);//adds textfield
          add(textfont, BorderLayout.NORTH);
          JPanel rows = new JPanel();
          rows.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 4));
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              NButtonList[i] = new JButton(NumberList[i]);
              rows.add(NButtonList[i]); //add's the buttons
              NButtonList[i].addActionListener(this);
              add(rows, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
              SButtonList[i] = new JButton(SymbolList[i]);
              rows.add(SButtonList[i]); //add's the buttons
              SButtonList[i].addActionListener(this);
              add(rows, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          }

          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //closes window button when pressing the x(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
          //add(button);//adds a button to the window//adds componenets to jframe//event
          setTitle("Calculator"); //sets title on top of window
      }

      private static double stringToDouble(String stringObject) {
          return Double.parseDouble(stringObject.trim());
      }
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          try {

              PassesCorrect(e);




          } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {

              name.setText("Please re-press on a number");




          }

      }

      public void PassesCorrect(ActionEvent e) {

          String ButtonString = e.getActionCommand();
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              if (e.getSource() == NButtonList[i]) {

                  name.setText(name.getText() + NumberList[i]); //appends text

              }
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
              if (e.getSource() == SButtonList[i]) {
                  //number = Double.parseDouble(name.getText());
                  name2.setText(SymbolList[i]);
              }
          }

          if (e.getSource() == SButtonList[0]) //checks if it's addition
          {

              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  number[i] = Double.parseDouble(name.getText()); //stores the number that has been entered into an array
              }
              //solution=name.getText();//gets the text and adds it into a string
              name.setText("+"); //sets the number from string and input's it on screen
              AddStatement = true;

          } else if (e.getSource() == SButtonList[1]) //checks if subtraction
          {

              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  number[i] = Double.parseDouble(name.getText());
              }

              //solution=name.getText();//gets the text and adds it into a string
              name.setText("-"); //sets the number from string and input's it on screen
              SubtractStatement = true;

          } else if (e.getSource() == SButtonList[2]) {
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  number[i] = Double.parseDouble(name.getText());
              }


              //solution=name.getText();//gets the text and adds it into a string
              name.setText("/"); //sets the number from string and input's it on screen
              DivideStatement = true;

          } else if (e.getSource() == SButtonList[3]) {
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  number[i] = Double.parseDouble(name.getText());
              }


              //solution=name.getText();//gets the text and adds it into a string
              name.setText("*"); //sets the number from string and input's it on screen
              MultiplyStatement = true;

          } else if (e.getSource() == SButtonList[5]) {
              name.setText("");
              SubtractStatement = false;
              AddStatement = false;
              DivideStatement = false;
              MultiplyStatement = false;

          } else if (e.getSource() == SButtonList[4]) //checks if it's equal sign
          {

              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  result[i] = Double.parseDouble(name.getText());
              }


              if (SubtractStatement == true) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                      result[i] = number[i] - result[i];
                      name.setText(Double.toString(result[i]));
                  }




              } else if (AddStatement == true) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                      result[i] = number[i] + result[i];
                      name.setText(Double.toString(result[i]));
                  }

                  //result+=number;


              } else if (MultiplyStatement == true) {

              } else if (DivideStatement == true) {
                  //result=number/result;
                  //name.setText(Double.toString(result));
              }
              SubtractStatement = false;
              AddStatement = false;
              DivideStatement = false;
              MultiplyStatement = false;


          }
      }
  }


  public class GUI2 {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          Colorwindow W1 = new Colorwindow();
          W1.setVisible(true);


      }
```

Comment: Sorry but your code style is so bad that I refuse to read it.  The indentation is a mess, line breaking is wrong, white-space-between-symbols is wrong, identifier conventions violated, heaps of commented out code.  Please read a Java Style Guide and fix this ... if you want other people to spend their time reading your code to help you.

Comment: narrow down your codes

Comment: I'd suggest learning about the IDE debugger before learning GUI programming, then use those skills to find out the error here, or you create a [mcve], please

Comment: Why are you using so many `for` loops in your code? If this is just a normal calculator you don't need most (or maybe any) of them.

Comment: Also, take some time to read [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and become familiar with them. This will make it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: @D.B. Tested his code without the `for` loops. Output is the same as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're reading in the subtraction sign as part of the second number, and then still subtracting.

E.g. `2-3` is encoded as `2` and `-3`, and then you do `first-second`, which turns into `2-(-3)` which is essentially addition.

You could change it to do addition in both cases, but this fails once you move on to multiplication and division as as `+4` and `-4` are valid numbers, but `*4` and `/4` are not.

Instead, do

```
else if(e.getSource()==SButtonList[4])//checks if it's equal sign
              {
                  for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
                  {
                  if(name.getText().length()>0) //make sure this string isn't empty
                    result[i] = Double.parseDouble(name.getText().substring(1));
```

This will get the characters except the first (which is the sign) from your string.

That being I haven't read your entire program, and if there are any cases where a number *without* a sign is present when this `if` is entered, you might end up trimming off the first digit, so be careful.

---

**Also, unless there is a very good reason you are doing every calculation 10 times in a `for` loop, you should remove those.** Your program works identically (just tested it) with all `number[i]` changed to `number`, `result[i]` to `result`, and `for` loops from 1-10 removed. (You also have to change your declarations for `number` and `result`)

Comment: How can i show a minus without applying it to the number on the display?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have another question, how am i able to do multiple out puts at the same time? For example when i do 3+2*3 it will only get the last and 2nd before last number as output and multiply it, getting an answer of 6 instead of adding 3 to 2*3.

Comment: @ChristopherMoran I think that has big enough scope that you should ask a new question for it. It involves doing order of operations and basic parsing techniques.